# What exactly lead into merge-conflicts in git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

1) There's a 'master' branch with a file containing

1

2

3

4

5

2) A takes a branch from 'master' and edit like

1

2

100

3

4

5

3) B takes a branch from 'master' and edit like

1

2

3

4

200

5

4) Now A push changes into master. Then B tries to push too.

What will happen with B? Any merge-conflicts or no merge-conflicts? Reasons?

Comment: B will be told to merge changes from A first. I guess with simple changes like that, there will be no conflict

Comment: Thanx for the response. I am asking this to try to figure out how exactly merge conflicts happens. :) It'll be helpful to have a direct answer for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the simplest answer is: git will assume there is a conflict if two devs have changed the same line of code in the same file (and same branch).

whoever commits and pushes first is the "winner". the second one has to deal with conflicts. he cannot push until he has pulled all changes from origin and resolved the conflicts.

Comment: This one exactly addressed my question.

Answer (score 6):

Your question implies something that is not the case.

Specifically, `git push` only pushes *existing commits*.  It does not merge anything, and in fact, it never even *tries* to merge anything.

In your question, there are three entities (people and repositories) involved.  Person A (let's call her Alice), person B (let's call him Bob), and person C (let's call him Central-Server and he's actually just a machine, not a person, though this is not important).

Alice and Bob both start by obtaining a copy (a clone) of some repository from Central-Server.  They get *exactly the same* clones (which is why they are called "clones"): Alice's clone matches Bob's clone matches what's on Central-Server.  They do this by running `git clone <url>` where `<url>` points to the central server (github or whatever it may be), and their git saves away the url under the name `origin` (we'll see this name again soon).

Let's make a drawing of (part of) the git commit graph that all three entities have right now:

```
... - C7 - C8   <-- master
```

Now Alice and Bob both make changes, but they make *different* changes.  Alice commits her change:

```
... - C7 - C8 - A   <-- master
```

Then Alice runs `git push origin` to push her work back to Central-Server.  Central-Server looks at her request, which says "add commit `A` to the end of the chain at `C8`, and make `master` point to `A`".  This operation *adds new commits* to the chain, and is therefore allowed, so Central-Server replies "OK" to Alice, and she is all finished.  Central-Server's repository now looks the same as Alice's as well, as both of them have new commit `A` after old commit `C8`, with `master` pointing to commit `A` (and commit `A` pointing back to the old `C8`).

Meanwhile Bob has made his change and also added a new commit, and his commit graph now looks like this:

```
... - C7 - C8 - B   <-- master
```

Bob has no idea that Alice has made commit `A`, nor successfully pushed it to Central-Server.  He goes to `git push origin`, but this time Central-Server gets a request that says "add commit `B` to the end of the chain at C8, then make `master` point to `B`".  **If Central-Server did this**, the effect would be:

```
                A
              /
... - C7 - C8 - B   <-- master
```

That is, commit `A` would be left floating with nothing pointing to it.  (Branch `master` would point to `B` and `B` would point back to `C8`, with nothing pointing to `A`.)  This is generally a bad state of affairs and git rejects it, so that Central-Server tells Bob:

```
rejected (non-fast-forward)
```

Note that there has been no merging and no rebasing.

It is now *Bob*'s job to do the merge (or rebase).  He should do so by:

1. Obtaining the update from someone who has it.  Who has it?  Alice has it, but so does Central-Server.  He just asked to push to Central-Server, who told Bob "no", so he might as well get it from Central-Server.
2. Do the merge (or rebase), resolving any conflicts.
3. Retry the push.

If Bob chooses "merge" and does a proper job of merging, here is his new commit graph:

```
... - C7 - C8 - A - M   <-- master
              \   /
                B
```

Note the new *merge commit* `M`.  Now Bob can re-try the push to Central-Server, who currently has the chain ending with `A`.  This time Central-Server will see a request to make `master` point to `M`, and since `M` points to `A`, that request will be allowed (it is now a "fast-forward").

Of course, if Alice (or Dave or Emily or Frank) beats Bob to the punch by adding new commits past `A` and sending them back to Central-Server, Bob will have to merge (or rebase) yet again, and try again.

#### How does Bob manage all this?

It's Bob's choice whether to merge or rebase.  Either way, Bob will have to solve any merge conflicts—and he will get the same merge conflicts, whichever method he uses.  And, in either case, he should start by running:

```
git fetch origin
```

(or just `git fetch`, which will use `origin` automatically).

Let's take a look at Bob's commit graph *before* a rebase or merge:

```
                A   <-- origin/master
              /
... - C7 - C8
              \
                B   <-- master
```

Note that Bob's `master` points to commit `B`, and Bob has this other thing—this `origin/master`—pointing to Alice's commit `A`.  This is what `git fetch` does: it brings over the latest version from Central-Server (or if Bob fetches directly from Alice, brings it over from her, since she has same commit), and then makes some label point to that commit.  The label starts with `origin/...` because that's the name we allowed `git clone` to use: it just sticks `origin/` in front of the other name (`master`, in this case) so that we can tell them apart.

If Bob chooses to *rebase* rather than merge, he will have his git *copy* his commit `B` to a new commit `B'`:

```
                A       <-- origin/master
              /   \
... - C7 - C8       B'  <-- master
              \
                B
```

What happens to Bob's original `B`?  The answer is: it is abandoned.  It remains in the repository for a while (default 30 days) in case Bob needs it back, saved in Bob's *reflogs*, but unless you (or Bob) explicitly ask git to look there, you do not see these commits, so they *seem* gone.

If Bob chooses to *merge*, he gets this:

```
                A       <-- origin/master
              /   \
... - C7 - C8       M   <-- master
              \   /
                B
```

This is *the same graph* we drew above, we've just lifted the `A` node up so that we can have an arrow pointing to it (labeled `origin/master`).

In either case, Bob can now try the push, since his new commit—either `B'` or `M`—points back to commit `A`, so that he is only asking Central-Server to *add new commits* rather than forget-or-abandon commit `A`.

#### What about the merge itself?

Git will attempt to help Bob out, by comparing the changes Alice made (adding a line with `100`) to the change Bob made (adding a line with `200`).  If git decides that these changes *do not* collide with each other, it will keep both changes.  If it decides that the two changes affect the *same part* of the file, it will give Bob a *merge conflict*, marking the changed regions of the file, and make Bob decide how to combine them.

Bob can use whatever he likes to achieve the combined result.  It is up to Bob to make sure that the result is correct, and then Bob should tell his git to `git add` the final version of the file and `git commit` to commit the changes.<sup>1</sup>  If the command he used to combine the changes was `git merge`, this will make a merge commit.  If it was `git rebase`, this will make the new copy `B'`.

---

<sup>1</sup>If Bob chose `git rebase`, he can just use `git rebase --continue`, and it will make the commit for him.  It is safe for Bob to do the `git commit` first and then do the `git rebase --continue`, though (and back in the days of git 1.5 or so, one did have to do the commit part manually, before continuing the rebase).

#### A final note about `git pull`

I encourage new git users to start with `git fetch` and then to do their own `git merge` or `git rebase`.  Many documents tell you to start with `git pull`, but I think this is a mistake.  The `git pull` command is meant to be a *convenience*: it runs `git fetch` and then runs either `git merge` or `git rebase`, but this has several flaws.  None are terribly serious any more, but these are not good for new users:

1. It chooses the merge vs rebase *before* you can even look at the changes.
2. The default is merge, which is usually the wrong answer for new users, who usually probably should rebase.  You can change the default, but new users don't know to do that in advance.  You can add `--rebase` to tell it to rebase, but you can forget to include this flag.
3. The merge it makes is a ["foxtrot merge"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452): it has the parent commits in the wrong direction.
4. The arguments are confusing when compared to manual merge: `git pull origin <branch>` vs `git merge origin/<branch>`.  (Of course, if you want to avoid foxtrot merges, you cannot use the latter either, but you probably should be rebasing anyway.)
5. If you supply too many arguments (`git pull origin master develop`), it makes an *octopus merge*, which is not something new users should even think about. :-)
6. It used to have a number of work-destroying bug cases.  I believe they are all fixed, but using `git fetch` followed by a separate `git merge` or `git rebase` has always avoided these bugs.
7. Last, there is just too much magic happening here.  It is supposed to be *convenient* (and for those who are old hands with git, it is convenient) but it just winds up being obscure.

Answer (score 1):

Merge conflicts occur when git does not know how to handle two changes in the same part of a code, which have not been made sequentially. In your case, the lines that have been changed are different, so git will be able to merge the commits without conflicts. However, once the commit in A has been pushed, the commit in B cannot be pushed without rebasing it on top of A.

In this situation you cannot push B:

```
----M-----A
     \----B
```

If you go to B and type and use:

```
git rebase A
```

your code will look like the following in your local repository:

```
----M-----A-----B
```

and you will be able to push commit B too

Answer (score 0):

When B tries to push, there will be error return, because A has been pushed changes to master.
Then you should do,

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

When doing rebase step, there is no conflicts happen, because A changes line 3 of the file, B changes line 5 of the file.
then you can do,

```
git commit -m ""
git push
```

Comment: i believe a rebase is too much in this case. a simple "git pull" will have the same effort

Comment: I tried it again, for one remote branch "git pull" and "git rebase" both is OK, "git pull" is more simple.
But for different branch, "git rebase" can only be used.