# Why can't I pull from my remote branch?

Tags: git, branch, git-rebase, git-pull

```
[console]: git remote -v
origin git@testServer.com:myProj/myProj.git(fetch)
origin git@testServer.com:myProj/myProj.git(push)

[console]: git branch -a
*myBranch
development
remotes/origin/myBranch
remotes/origin/development

[console]: git pull origin/myBranch myBranch
fatal: 'origin/myBranch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

I originally made this branch and have been pushing to it for a while.  Although yesterday I did rebase from another branch into my branch so maybe that messed something up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong: it's `git pull [ remote [ branch-name ] ]`, not `git pull remote/branch-name branch-name`.  In this case you would need `git pull origin myBranch`.

That said, I recommend *not* using `git pull` at all, at least not until you are very familiar with Git.  The reason is that `git pull` does two things, and the second thing it does is run `git merge`, which:

- can fail to happen automatically, stop in the middle, and need help from you;
- produces ["foxtrot merges"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452), which are sort of backwards, whenever it makes a real merge;
- is usually better done as `git rebase` anyway.

The first half of `git pull` is `git fetch`, so you can just run `git fetch` and then, after it succeeds, run either `git merge` or `git rebase` as desired.  Both of these commands take much more sensible arguments than `git pull`.

With `git fetch`, you name the remote to fetch from, e.g., `git fetch origin` (or just let `git fetch` figure it out: `git fetch` with no arguments will generally figure out to use `origin` automatically).

With both `git merge` and `git rebase`, you name the `origin/myBranch` remote-tracking branch, or just let Git figure it out, again.

All that also said, `git pull` will usually figure all of these out on its own as well.  In particular if `git merge` or `git rebase` can figure out to use `origin/myBranch`, `git pull` can figure out to use `origin` and `origin/myBranch` for its two steps.

Answer (score 6):

The correct syntax is `git pull origin myBranch`
The first argument of the command should be the name of the remote, as suggested by the error `fatal: 'origin/myBranch' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: I just found out today that git pull origin branch isn't working as I'd expect... after I do it, I always check that my sha's are the same with git branch -a -vv.  They weren't though... so I checked out my local version of that remote branch and did a git pull ... it updated.. then i went back to the branch I had been working on and did a git pull origin branch again and THIS time there were updates... so its almost like git pull origin branch was ONLY looking at my local branch copy... wth?