# Git Order of Commits after Merging Branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've been attempting the branching model as described in the following article:
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

1. I made a new branch called items from master, made a few commits over there
2. Went back to branch master and made a single commit
3. `git merge --no-ff` the branch item then resolve any merge conflicts

I assumed that all merged commits from the other branch would be brought in together in order, however that does not seem the case. The following is the output of `git log`:

```
f28e150 Merge branch 'items'
8281666 [Master] Another middle commit before merge
73d0ca9 [items] commit 2
0442978 [items] commit 1
```

Why are the first two commits of item branch showing before the master branch? Wouldn't it make more sense to show them together under the merge commit since thats when I merged it all with my code?

Calling the graph option: `git log --graph` shows it in the correct order

```
*   f28e150 Merge branch 'items'
|\  
| * 73d0ca9 [items] commit 2
| * 0442978 [items] commit 1
* | 8281666 [Master] Another middle commit before merge
|/
```

The reason I want them all together is to make it easier for me to undo the entire merge

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The short answer is that `git log` sorts its output, and you must choose the sort order that you prefer.  (It sorts because it *must*: [parent/child relationships in a graph provide only a *partial order*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/367583) but `git log` needs to impose a *total order*.)

The details are described in [the `git log` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html#_commit_ordering), which is very long; search for `commit ordering` (the link here should take you directly to it).

The claim of "reverse chronological order" default is a bit of a lie now (it was true in older versions of Git), so the order you get by default will depend on your particular version of Git.  Note that `--graph` turns on `--topo-order` automatically, so `--topo-order` may be what you want.

Note also that you can restrict the revision walking to look *only* at the *first* parent of each merge, using `--first-parent`.  In this case you won't see the other branch at all.  For `--first-parent` to be useful, everyone who merges needs to be somewhat careful about it, so that you do not have "foxtrot merges" shoving commits over into side branches.  See [GIT: How can I prevent foxtrot merges in my 'master' branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However when you do a git reset for the past x number of commits, which order will be used?

Comment: The `git reset` command itself does not use this kind of numbering system.  However, `gitrevisions` *does* allow `<identifier>~n` (e.g., `HEAD~5`).  This follows *parent links*, specifically *first parent* links.  That's not a `git reset` thing but rather a general purpose "name a specific commit by relation" thing, and you can use, e.g., `git show` to see that particular commit.  There are (many) more details in https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html