# Change direction of git merge (after the merge is done)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-patch

I have a branch (e.g. Feature-X) in a git repo.

What I did was the following

```
git checkout master
git merge Feature-X
```

There were quite a few conflicts which I resolved. I haven't committed the changes yet.

But, it turns out what I wanted was to do the reverse merge (i.e. merge master into Feature-x) because the branch is probably still unstable.

Is there any command that can salvage the work I did in resolving the conflicts or do I need to do the resolution once more, this time in the branch Feature-X?

I'm thinking whether there is a way to get the current patch but apply it in branch Feature-X in the "reverse" order. E.g. when the patch says that line X changed to Y, this is relative to Feature-X going to master. If I want to do the opposite, the patch should say that line Y changed to X, right? This is just my thoughts. Any solution is OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### TL;DR: see the end

There is a "recipe" at the end; scroll down to find it (and then up a bit to find the description and explanation and slightly safer method).

#### Good news and bad news

In a significant sense, merges don't exactly *have* a "direction".  (The direction you "see" when you look at a merge is a product of your imagination, plus the merge commit's message, plus one more important thing that will be our "bad news"—but it's not fatally bad, in the end.)

Consider this diagram of a pair of branches with commit `*` as their merge base:

```
          o--o--...--o   <-- branch1
         /
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--...--o   <-- branch2
```

The process of merging ("merge as a verb") `branch1` and `branch2` is achieved by:

- comparing, i.e., `git diff`, the merge base commit `*` to the tip commit of `branch1`;
- comparing the merge base to the tip of `branch2`;
- then, starting from the base, *combining* both sets of changes.

Hence the actual merge itself should look like this:

```
          o--o--...--o
         /            \
...--o--*              M
         \            /
          o--o--...--o
```

(I named the merge commit `M` since we don't know, or really care, what crazy Git hash ID `deadbeef` or `badc0ffee` or whatever it will have.)  The eventual merge commit `M` *is* the merge ("merge as a noun"); it stores the final source tree, based on the merge-as-a-verb combining process.

Which "direction" is this merge?  Well, that depends, at least in part, on what labels we stick on it, doesn't it? :-)  Note that I carefully stripped away both `branch1` and `branch2`.  Let's put them back:

```
          o--o--...--o     <-- branch1?
         /            \
...--o--*              M   <-- branch1? branch2?
         \            /
          o--o--...--o     <-- branch2?
```

This might look confusing.  It probably *is* confusing.  It's a big part of the whole issue.  **The bad news is, it's not the *whole* thing.**  There's something we cannot quite capture in these drawings.  It may not matter to you, and if it does, it's not that big a deal anyway; we'll fix it up by making one more merge commit.  But for now, let's just press on.

#### Making the merge commit

Once we make the merge commit `M` itself, we have to choose—or have Git choose-*which branch it's on*.  In a simple, unconflicted merge, we always end up having Git choose this.  What Git *does* is simple: whatever branch we are on, when we start the `git merge` command, is the branch that *gets* the merge commit.  So:

```
git checkout branch1
git merge branch2
```

means that the final picture is:

```
          o--o--...--o
         /            \
...--o--*              M   <-- branch1
         \            /
          o--o--...--o     <-- branch2
```

which we can re-draw as:

```
...--o--*--o--...--o--M   <-- branch1
         \           /
          o---...---o     <-- branch2
```

which makes it obvious that we merged branch2 into branch1, not vice versa.  Nonetheless, the *source code* attached to commit `M` does not depend on this "merge direction".

#### Sidebar: Conflicted merges

Conflicted merges are just like unconflicted merges in terms of final result.  It's just that Git can't do the merge on its own.  It stops and makes *you* resolve the conflicts, and then run `git commit` to make the merge commit.  That final `git commit` step makes merge commit `M`.

The new merge commit goes on the *current branch*, just like any other commit.  So that's how `M` winds up on `branch1`.  Note that the merge commit's *message* also says something about which branch name was merged into which other branch name—but you have a chance to edit this while you make the commit, so you can change that to suit whatever whim you may have. :-)

(In fact, this is no different from the unconflicted case: both run `git commit` to make the final merge commit, and both give you a chance to edit the message.)

#### The bad news

The bad news is that these diagrams omit something that *may* matter to you.  Git has a notion of *first parent:* a merge commit like `M` has two parents, so one of these is the *first* parent and one is not.<sup>1</sup>  That *first parent* is how you tell which branch you were on when you made the merge.

Hence, while these diagrams, and the merge-as-a-verb *process*, show that there isn't exactly a "merge direction", this first-parent notion proves that there is.  **If you will ever use this first-parent notion,** you will care about this, and want to get it right.  Fortunately, there is a solution.  (In fact, there are multiple solutions, but I'll show the klunky-but-straightforward ones first.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Obviously, the other one is the second parent: there are only two parents.  Git allows, however, merge commits with three or more parents.  You can enumerate all parents whenever you have to; but Git considers the *first* especially important, and has `--first-parent` flags to various commands, so as to follow "the original branch".

---

#### Getting the merge we want

Let's go ahead and make the "wrong" merge commit:

```
# git add ...    (if needed)
git commit
```

Now we have:

```
          o--o--...--o     <-- [old branch1 tip]
         /            \
...--o--*              M   <-- branch1
         \            /
          o--o--...--o     <-- branch2
```

where `M`'s *first parent* is the old `branch1` tip.

What we want now is to make a *new* merge commit (with different ID) that's the *same* as `M` except that:

- `branch2` points to it
- its first parent is the tip of `branch2`
- its second parent is the *previous* tip of `branch1`

The trick is to save commit `M` somehow—that's easy enough, we'll use a temporary name so we don't have to copy down `M`'s hash ID—and then reset `branch1`:

```
git branch temp          # or git tag temp
git reset --hard HEAD~1  # move branch1 back, dropping M
```

(note that this is the same as [brehonia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43257478/1256452), so far).  We now have this graph, which is quite unchanged except for the *labels* attached to each commit:

```
          o--o--...--o     <-- branch1
         /            \
...--o--*              M   <-- temp
         \            /
          o--o--...--o     <-- branch2
```

Now check out `branch2` and run the merge over again; it will fail with conflicts as before:

```
git checkout branch2
git merge branch1        # use --no-commit if Git would commit the merge
```

The commit we have not yet made is the same, in a sense, as the merge commit `M`—but once we make it, its *first* parent will be the current tip of `branch2`, and its *second* parent will be the current tip of `branch1`.  We just need to get the right *source* to go with this commit we're going to make.

Now we use the merge *result* we saved with the name `temp`.  This assumes you're in the top level of your tree, so that `.` names everything:

```
git rm -rf -- .          # remove EVERYTHING
git checkout temp -- .   # get it all back from temp
```

We are now using the merge result we committed earlier.  We do not even have to `git add` anything as this form of `git checkout` updates the index, so:

```
git commit
```

and we have our new merge `M2`, on branch `branch2`, as desired:

```
          o--o--...--o__   <-- branch1
         /            \ \
...--o--*              M \ <-- temp
         \            /   \
          o--o--...--o-----M2   <-- branch2
```

Now we can delete the temporary branch or tag:

```
git branch -D temp   # or git tag -d temp
```

and we are all done.  With the temporary name gone, we can't *see* the original merge `M` any more.

#### Sneaky plumbing method

There's actually a shorter way to do all this, using Git's "plumbing" commands, but it's a bit tricky.  Once we have everything `git add`-ed and have run `git commit`, we have the right tree, we just have a commit that has the wrong first and second parent IDs.  You may wish to edit the commit *message* as well, so that it looks like you're merging branch1 into branch2 in the message.  Then:

```
# git add ...    (if / as needed, as above)
# git commit     (make the merge)
git branch -f branch2 $(git log --pretty=format:%B --no-walk HEAD |
    git commit-tree -p HEAD^2 -p HEAD^1 -F -)
git reset --hard HEAD^1
```

The `git commit-tree` step makes a new merge commit that's a copy of the one we just made, but with the two parents swapped.  We then make `branch2` point to this commit, using `git branch -f`.  *Be sure you get the name (`branch2`) right at this step.*  The `HEAD^1` and `HEAD^2` names refer to the two (first and second) parents of the *current* commit, which is of course the merge commit we just made.  That has the right tree, and the right commit message text; it just has the wrong first and second parent hashes.

Once we have the new commit safely added to `branch2`, we simply reset our current (`branch1`) branch back to remove the merge commit we made.

Comment: Would you mind adding the visual diagram to some of the steps in the `Getting the merge we want` section, so that we can see what is going on? Would be much easier to follow along and visualise in our head..personally I got a bit lost there.

Comment: @CyberMew: see if those help. Graph-drawing can get difficult as the graph gets tangled...

Comment: +1 Great explanation on why merges don't have a direction, and yet they do (in a sense). Really helpful graphs.

Comment: Merge direction MATTERS!  Look at the resulting merge-commit between "Merge A into B" (i.e. checkout B during merge) and "Merge B into A" (i.e. checkout A during merge).  There are completely different, and they give you a sense of what's was the development flow.  Of course, the contents of the merge-commit is the same, but the history that it read out will be different.

Comment: @Ryuu: it matters in terms of first-parent vs second-parent, and of course, which branch *name* Git updates once Git makes the commit. But we can change the commit hashes to which a branch *name* points at any time, which means we can, if we want, do the merge "backwards", then shuffle the names around. This leaves only the first vs second parent, which is what the answer is all about: in the end, we might want to use `git commit-tree` to copy the wrong-parent-order merge to a different corrected merge, while retaining the tree etc.

Comment: @torek: yeah, I agree.  I've been doing the reversals when other team mates messes with parenting, and this really clutters the graph;  The only issue that I have with this answer is that the important part is buried in the middle, and titled as "The bad news" (not obvious).  A skimmer who just read the first few paragraphs, will conclude as "this whole thing doesn't matter";

Comment: @Ryuu: the problem is, some people really *don't* care. Others (including me) do. Note that `git pull` makes these same "backwards" merges (what some call a [foxtrot merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452)), although that may be less important than for feature branches.

Comment: @torek: Yeah, you are right. I'm losing the battle trying to convince my teammates;  Foxtrot: yeah, I'm facing that too. Thanks for pointing me to that link! I'm tempted to use that hook, but I am worried that some teammates might not be able to understand how to fix it. I'm looking at Git Flow as a potential solution.

Answer (score 4):

Commit the merge on master, create a new branch on that commit, and reset the master branch to the previous commit.

```
git branch temp
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

(This is assuming there's nothing else in your working copy you want to keep, you would lose it in the reset!)

You're back where you started (pre-merge) but your conflict resolutions are safe if you want them.

Now try the merge again, the right way round (master -> feature). If you're lucky there won't be as many conflicts this way and you can just get it done.

If that's no good for you, you could merge or cherry-pick your temp branch into feature. It won't look right on the graph but that's the price!

Remember to delete your extra branch when you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You can do several things:

1. do it manually using `git rebase -i` and manually reverse the order of your commits.
2. write a script that will loop over the `git log --reverse` and will update the commits in the order that you wish it to be.
3. next time use the `git rebase --onto` and decide where you wish to start your commits

> **`--onto <newbase>`**
>    Starting point at which to create the new commits. If the --onto option is not specified, the starting point is . May be any valid commit, and not just an existing branch name.
>
> As a special case, you may use "A...B" as a shortcut for the merge base of A and B if there is exactly one merge base. You can leave out at most one of A and B, in which case it defaults to HEAD.

[image]