# Control Freak: Commit rejected. Foxtrot merges not allowed in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

What exactly is the reason for `Control Freak: Commit rejected. Foxtrot merges not allowed`

We keep receiving this error quite often, is this is caused due to a combination of `pull`, `rebase` and `amend` by users while committing?

Need clarity to get rid of this permanently. I know and understand the branch has diverged and it has lost the trace but what exactly has caused that to happen in simple language is highly appreciable

It's a time killer for us to rebase every time when we see this error. We are manually cherry-picking the change to get rid of this.

How to identify the committed type like was that a right commit after
rebase or pull or amended and which exactly is the commit that and by
whom?

We want to educate developers to come out of similar commit mistakes
henceforth. Would love to hear about the best practices.

Also, want to understand is there any reason for combination tools like git-bash/source-tree?

Can we turn off this cause by any chance?

[image]

Comment: I have to say I have never heard of "foxtrot" merges before.  [Here is a blog post](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/stop-foxtrots-now/) which seems to do a good job of explaining.  The solution here is to fix your Git workflow, and stop using foxtrot merges.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is related to [Foxtrot merges](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/stop-foxtrots-now/), specifcally prohibited on BitBucket:

> A foxtrot merge is a specific sequence of git commits. A particularly nefarious sequence. Out in the open, in lush open grasslands, the sequence looks like this:

[image: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/stop-foxtrots-now/02-foxtrot.png]

> But foxtrots are rarely seen in the open. They hide up in the canopy, in-between the branches. I call them foxtrots because, when caught mid-pounce, they look like the foot sequence for the eponymous ballroom dance:

[image: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/stop-foxtrots-now/foxtrot-redrawn.png]

> Foxtrot merges are bad because they change origin/master’s first-parent history.
>
> The parents of a merge commit are ordered. The first parent is HEAD. The second parent is the commit you reference with the git merge command.
>
> You can think of it like this:

```
git checkout 1st-parent
git merge 2nd-parent
```

If pushed:

[image: https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/stop-foxtrots-now/05-foxtrot-pushed.png]

As explained in "[GIT: How can I prevent foxtrot merges in my 'master' branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/6309)", commit '`D`' is a foxtrot merge because '`origin/master`' is its 2nd parent.
This is the result of a pull (fetch + merge)
Once that fox-trot merge D is pushed... the first-parent history of '`origin/master`' no longer contains commit '`B`'!

As explained by [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) in "[how to avoid foxtrot merge in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156429/6309)", this is the result of working directly on `master` (new commit `C`), and doing a git pull (instead of a `pull --rebase`, [as I always advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309))

That will merge `B` and `C` into `D` (the foxtrot merge), which, once pushed, means the `origin/master` no longer has `B` as direct ancestor, but `C`.
Your work 'C' now becomes the main published branch history (`origin/master`), instead of `B`, relegated to something that was merged.

Comment: Thank you @VonC, but how to track the commit in detail

Comment: @Mithun the commit, it is a history of commits that would show a foxtrot merge, not just a commit": `git log --all --decorate --oneline --decorate --branches` is a start to see what is going on.

Comment: I can see the complete history, but will there be any indication of term: `Foxtrot`?

Comment: @Mithun No: it is a merge pattern, not a Git "term" that would appear in the logs.

Comment: will git squash all commits in branch help to resolve this foxtrot issue?

Comment: @Mithun No: this is more about rebasing C branch on top of B branch, instead of merging B branch into C branch.

Comment: I usually do it with pull, and never faced such issues but from some days we are facing this

Comment: @Mithun Can you try with https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309? With `pull.rebase` and `rebase.autoStash`, you should minimize/avoid any spurious merge entirely, hence avoiding any Foxtrox merge occurrence.

Comment: @Mithun I mean: what torek said in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156429/6309, but my setting is a practical answer to your second question. I am at work right now. I will reopen your question and put an answer later today.

Comment: Many developers tag major versions then squash all the commits in-between. In this case blocking foxtrot commits holds no value.

Comment: @Tim I suppose BitBucket did not intially had the same kind of squash and merge process as GitHub (https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges#squash-and-merge-your-pull-request-commits), which might explain why they are blocking this kind of merge. BitBucket does have the same now (https://www.atlassian.com/blog/bitbucket/new-features-bitbucket-4-9)

Comment: Even though this pretends to explain the situation... for me it fails. I do not get it. Might be just me. But the examples, the explanation, everything here is weak and inconsistent. Why is there a "git checktout 1st-parent" and "git merge 2nd parent" and in the picture the commits are named A B C? What is the relation between the text and the pictures? Please. More explanation.

Comment: @Zordid I understand. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to avoid this problem is to always run "git pull --rebase" and to never run default "git pull".  Here's a deep dive blog post on that:  [Too much fun with "git pull --rebase"](https://mergebase.com/doing-git-wrong/2018/03/07/fun-with-git-pull-rebase/)

The reason you're encountering this problem is because your company has installed the free [Control Freak](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1217635/control-freak-for-bitbucket-server?hosting=server&tab=overview) plugin for Bitbucket and they have left its default [Foxtrot Prevention](https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/04/stop-foxtrots-now/) control enabled for all branches.

If you're on Bitbucket Server 5.5 or newer you can rebase pull-requests directly from the pull request screen.  Click on the "..." button on the far right of the pull-request screen and a "Rebase" menu item should be available.

Alternatively you can ask an admin to disable the foxtrot prevention.  Even repo admins can do this (does not require global admins).  But I don't recommend disabling this control since it prevents messy commit history.

Full disclosure:  I wrote and maintain the free "Control Freak" plugin for Bitbucket Server.

Note: rebases and amends should never cause foxtrots.  Typically only default "git pull" causes foxtrot merges, and "git pull -r" is a great remedy.  The "git merge" command can also cause it, but it's rare for people to accidentally create a foxtrot merge when using "git merge" in typical scenarios that call for "git merge".  I suspect 99% of the time it's "git pull" that is causing the problem.

Comment: We're frequently running into foxtrot merges when trying to make sure that the current `feature` branch is compatible with `master` by merging `master` into `feature`. This is preferred over `rebasing` on `master` since the latter often requires tedious resolving of merge conflicts in many commits of the `feature` branch instead of resolving them all in one go in a merge commit. Is there a way of keeping the simplicity of a single commit to resolve all issues but avoiding foxtrot merges?

Comment: When is the foxtrot warning happening?  When you finally try to merge into 'master'?  Or at a different time?

Comment: When merging to master (via a PR). Shall we move this to a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204176/g-sylvie-davies-and-nitzel)?