# Foxtrot Merge: How to solve it

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, git-pull

I have been working on a project and have been pushing code to my dev branch on remote git repository. Meanwhile, some changes were introduced in the master branch that I needed to fetch. So i used the following route:
1 - git checkout master
2 - git pull
3 - git checkout my_dev_branch
4 - git merge master

Now when I committed my changes to a pull request into master, It shows that the merge i performed is foxtrot merge. Should I revert or reset this earlier merge commit and then manually fetch those changes from master. Or is there any other solution available to this.

Currently, I have been looking to just revert to a commit before the merge but this article here "https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt" presents quite a gloomy and complicated picture. I don't want it to be that complicated of a task.
This answer ([How to revert a merge commit that's already pushed to remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-to-revert-a-merge-commit-thats-already-pushed-to-remote-branch)) is good enough?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, the commands you listed don't by themselves lead to a "foxtrot merge".  (See also [GIT: How can I prevent foxtrot merges in my 'master' branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452))  If you have one of these, you must have run `git merge` from your `master` to your `origin/master`, probably via `git pull`, after making a commit *on* your own `master`.  (This make-a-commit-on-your-own-`master` part is what *doesn't* show in your sequence of commands.)

In any case, you really don't want to *revert* the merge.  That leaves the merge in place, and adds another commit that has the effect of undoing the merge in terms of its effect on the source.  It's this second non-merge commit that leads to the subsequent mess in your linked kernel.org page.  If you *do* do this revert, what you end up with is a foxtrot merge, followed by more commits including the revert, followed by whatever you have to do later to re-merge the merge anyway.  So the foxtrot merge is still there!

In general, foxtrot merges are not all that bad.  They just have the main line work as the *second* parent of a feature, instead of as the *first* parent of a feature—but who is to say which line is the *main* line in the first place?  If you change your perspective, perhaps *your* feature *was* the main line after all, and the thing that everyone else has been calling the "main line" was actually the side feature.  That's all a foxtrot merge is: a change in perspective, to claim that *you* are the main line, and *they* are the side feature.

But if you don't like that, the only true cure is to rewrite your own history.  Since it's *your* history—your merge that declares that your commits are your main line—this *might* be OK, not only with you but with everyone else too.  It *is* OK if everyone else who has obtained your commits—your history—is not already depending on, and building on, these commits.  If they *are* depending on, and building on, these commits, it may *still* be OK: are all these other colleagues or coworkers OK with *redoing* their work, after you rewrite your own history?

If all of that is true—if no one else depends on your history, or all of those who do depend on it are willing to do even more work so that they can handle your rewriting of your history—then what you are to do is clear: *remove* your foxtrot merge from your `master`.  This requires careful use of `git reset`, and understanding how Git branches really work, what `git merge` does, and how branch *names* are not the key.  The key is the *commit graph*.

Making new commits adds to the graph, and updates whichever branch name you're "on"—in the sense that `git status` says "on branch ___"—so that that branch name identifies the new commit.  The new commit's parent—singular, in the case of most commits—is the commit that *was* the tip of the branch before.  If the new commit is a merge commit, the new commit's parents, plural, are the commit that *was* the tip of the branch before (as usual), and then—as a *second* parent—the commit you specified when you said to merge.

That is, a *branch* in Git is just a chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

The *name* `master` remembers a hash ID, in this case, `H` (`H` stands in for the actual hash ID, which is a big ugly string of hexadecimal representation of a 160-bit number, and which appears random, though it isn't).  Commit `H` is the *last* commit on the branch.  Git uses the hash ID in `master` to find the actual commit.  Commit `H` itself contains, i.e., remembers, a parent hash ID, `G`, that Git uses to find commit `G`.  Commit `G` remembers *its* parent `F`; Git uses this hash ID to find the actual commit `F`.  This process repeats, with Git walking the chain backwards, one commit at a time, to find all the commits that are "on"—more precisely, *reachable from*—the branch name.

When a branch name, or a commit, contains a hash ID for some other commit, we say that the branch name (or commit) *points to* the commit whose hash ID they contain.  So a branch name *points to* a—one, single—commit.  That commit *is* the tip of the branch.  That's simply Git's definition of "branch".

If you make some change(s) to some file(s) and then `git commit` the result, the new snapshot gets a new and unique big ugly hash ID, which we can call `I`.  The new commit `I` records hash ID `H`, so that `I` points back to `H`.  Then Git writes `I`'s commit hash ID into the name `master`, so that `master` points to `I`:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <--master
```

and that's how a branch grows.

When you use `git reset` (in the right way), you tell Git: *Change `master` so that instead of pointing to my new commit `I`, it points back to `H` instead.*  Commit `I` is not actually *gone:* it's still there, floating in space as it were.  But if `master` was the only *name* you had for it, it's now very hard to find its hash ID.  (Do you have it memorized? :-) )  Now instead of `master` pointing to `I` and `I` pointing to `H`, *now* you have:

```
             I
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

This is also how you get rid of a foxtrot merge.  Suppose you started with:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Someone else added *their* new `I` and `J` commits to *their* `master` (which your `git fetch` remembers as your `origin/master`):

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/master
```

You add a new commit, perhaps even a whole string of them, to your master, perhaps by merging your own `feature/tall`:

```
             K--L   <-- feature/tall
            /    \
...--F--G--H------M   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/master
```

Here, your merge commit `M` has shared `H` as its first parent (the "main line") and your commit `L` as its second parent (your feature).  Then you add a new commit `N` that makes their `J`, their `master` that's your `origin/master`, into a side branch, because your `M` is your main line:

```
             K--L   <-- feature/tall
            /    \
...--F--G--H------M--N   <-- master
            \       /
             I-----J   <-- origin/master
```

Their `J` is now a side branch, just like your `feature/tall`, because the *main* line runs `N`, `M`, `H`, `G`, `F`, ..., straight back along the main line—the sequence of first-parents.

If you want to perceive the main line as going back through `J`, you must eliminate *your* merge `M` entirely.  This requires making your `master` point to `H` again.  You might do this with:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <hash-of-H>
```

which we can then draw (messily) as:

```
               L   <-- feature/tall
              / \
             K ,-M-----N
            /_/       /
...--F--G--H   <-------- master
            \       /
             I-----J   <-- origin/master
```

Note that all the commits are still there—`N` still goes back to `M` and `J` as before, and `M` still goes back to both `H` and `L` as before—but there is no *name* that leads to `N`, and hence no way to find `N` or `M`.  We can therefore drop them from the drawing:

```
             K--L   <-- feature/tall
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- origin/master
```

Now all you need to do is slide your `master` forward-and-down to `J`, which you can do with `git merge --ff-only origin/master`:

```
             K--L   <-- feature/tall
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I--J   <-- master, origin/master
```

which we can now redraw even-less-messily:

```
             K--L   <-- feature/tall
            /
...--F--G--H--I--J   <-- master, origin/master
```

You're now ready to make a pull request, i.e., a request that *someone else* run `git merge` for you, in which you propose making a new merge—we can call it `M` again if we like—that will have as its *first* parent, commit `J`, and as its second parent, commit `L`: a non-foxtrot merge that calls the main line "the main line" and your feature a "feature".

This stuff *is* kind of hard.  The trick to understanding it is that commit **hash IDs** are universal: they're globally unique, and *every* repository that gets your commits, gets them by their hash IDs.  Your Git, and Joe's Git, Katherine's Git, Larry's Git, and so on, all agree that commit `H` is commit *`H`*.  It never has any other hash ID.  But the *names* that *your* Git uses—your branch names—are *yours*.  They don't need to appear in any other repository.  The names *they* use—*their* `master`, *their* `develop`, and so on—will show up in *your* Git as *your* `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and so on.  Running:

```
git fetch
```

makes your Git call up their Git, get any new commits—by hash IDs as always—and then update *your* `origin/*` names based on *their* names.  It's the `fetch` that gets their commits and updates your remote-tracking names, your `origin/*`.

When you run `git merge --no-ff`, or have Bitbucket or GitHub do this for you, *that* creates a new commit—which automatically gets a new, unique hash ID—and it is the new merge commit that records a first parent—the "main line"—and a second parent, the "feature, all by their *hash IDs*.  Any names, whether they're your branch names like `master` or your remote-tracking names like `origin/master`, become irrelevant once you actually have and keep the *commit* with its unique hash ID.

To put it another way: **Names find commits.  Only commits really matter.  Names matter only if, when, and because they find commits.**

(See also [how to avoid foxtrot merge in git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55155810/1256452). especially the comments.)

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer.

Comment: "_If you have one of these, you must have run git merge from your `master` to your `origin/master`_" - what do you mean by that? do you mean that `origin/master` is merged into local `master`? I cannot imagine this the other way even though your wording seems to point to that

Answer (score 1):

[branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKhzF.png)

In the above picture, merging back branch release/dev into GM-1166-SQS... will lead to a foxtrot merge.
To solve this, just first add a dummy commit on branch GM-1166-SQS-... and push it.
Now if you merge release/dev in GM-1166-.., it will not give a foxtrot error.
This is also a way to prevent foxtrot errors.

In other words, if branch A is merged into branch B, then if you need to merge C into A, first make a dummy commit on branch A and  only then merge C into A. Now you wont get a foxtrot merge when pushing.