# How to get changes from master into branch without rebase avoiding foxtrot

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, rebase

I'm working on some code using Git, Bitbucket and Sourcetree. I'm stuck in a very common scenario in which I need to get changes from the master branch (**master**) into some development branch **dev1**.

After a little research, it seems that there are two ways of doing so (this question summarizes both approaches: [Get changes from master into branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340724/get-changes-from-master-into-branch-in-git)):

1. Merge **master** into the development branch: Bitbucket has a plugin called Control-Freak which prevents foxtrott merges on master. So after a merge of **master** into **dev1** I am not allowed to merge **dev1** back to **master**, which is what I want to do after I finished work on **dev1**
2. Rebase **dev1**: I've read, that this should be avoided, when changes are already pushed to origin and more people are working on the same branch, which is the case. So this solution seems inappropriate as well.

Are there any other option, which I am not aware of?

Comment: Ask your admin to disable Control-Freak? What you're doing is perfectly valid. Control Freak prevents the foxtrot commits that result from careless use of `git pull`, but it ought to allow your use case. [Good explanation of foxtrot merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155550/control-freak-commit-rejected-foxtrot-merges-not-allowed-in-bitbucket) (But this question is not a duplicate, since that question does not cover your use case.)

Comment: Would merging into dev1 with a single rebase shortly before merging back to master be an option? Otherwise, disabling this control-freak would also be what I'd suggest. There's nothing wrong with merging two single commits.