# git - Find commit from which was branch created

Tags: git, branch

Is it possible to find commit (ideally only the commit hash) from which was branch created, even if the branch was **already merged**?

For example:

```
master   A-B-C-D-E
          \   /
feature    F-G
```

`feature` branch is already merged in `master`, but it still exists and can be checkout to. I would like to find, that `feature` branch started from `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branches don't really have parent branches.  (Related: [How to find the nearest parent of a Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3161204/1256452))  You can find the hash of `A` pretty easily, but consider this diagram:

```
H--I--L--N--O--R---T--U   <-- master
 \     \     \    /
  J--K--M--P--Q--S   <-- feature
```

Which commit(s) would you like to find here?  `O`, `L`, and `H` are all viable candidates for "where `feature` started from".  But maybe `feature` *didn't* start from *any* of those; maybe it started from `P`, which used to have a label `main-feature`.  See the related question for details.

To find commit `A` from your diagram, which I'll reproduce here a form I consider more accurate (the name `master` merely points directly to commit `E` for instance—commits `F` and `G` are on branch `master` too!):

```
A--B--C--D--E   <-- master
 \      /
  F----G   <-- feature
```

we can start from commit `E` (tip of master) and step back to commit `D` (the merge).  We know we have hit `D` when one of its parents is the tip of `feature`, i.e., is commit `G`.  We then get both parent hash IDs from commit `D`:

```
git rev-parse <hash-of-D>^@
```

and make sure there are exactly two of them (a three-parent merge makes this hard), and then invoke `git merge-base --all` on those two parent hash IDs.  This immediately produces the hash ID of commit `A`.

When we use this same procedure on my sample graph, we step back from `U` to `T`, discover that it has two parents and the second is `S` which is the tip of `feature`, and ask Git to find the merge base of `R` and `S`.  The output of this `git merge-base --all` is the hash of commit `O`.

To do this relatively quickly in shell script, start with:

```
git rev-list --merges --first-parent master
```

which produces a list of all merge commit hash IDs reachable by walking first-parent descendants of `master`.  (You may or may not want `--first-parent`; if you've been using `git pull` heavily, the first parent linkages of `master` may be somewhat damaged by ["foxtrot merges"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452).)  That is, this gives us commit hashes `T` and `D` in the two diagrams here (and probably more).  If you omit `--first-parent`, think about what you want from cases where other branches have merged into `master`, bringing with them commits from the `feature` branch in question, and decide whether you might want `--topo-order` in your `git rev-list`.

Next, walk through these commits, getting their parent hashes:

```
looking_for=$(git rev-parse feature)  # this is the hash ID we're looking for
found=false
for hash in (output of above git rev-list); do
    set -- $(git rev-parse ${hash}^@)
    case $# in
    2) # two parents, good
        if [ $2 == $looking_for ]; then found=true; break; fi;;
    *) # more than two parents, we might go wrong
        echo "commit $hash has $# parents, help"; exit 1;;
    esac
done
if ! $found; then
    echo "unable to find the commit hash you were looking for"
    exit 1
fi
```

At this point, you have the desired commit pair in `$1` and `$2` due to the way `set` parses arguments, so:

```
# found the desired commit pair, so now just invoke git merge-base
set -- $(git merge-base --all $1 $2)
case $# in
1) echo "the commit you are looking for is $1"; exit 0;;
*) echo "I found $# candidate commits $@"; exit 1;;
esac
```

Comment: That should be "=" not "==" in the shell script on line 7, but Stack Overflow won't let me make such a small edit.

Answer (score 1):

(**Disclaimer** : off-topic answer - not adressing *already merged* branches)

---

If `feature` and `master` are *not yet merged*, you can just get their "merge-base" ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base)) :

```
git merge-base master feature
```

It will output your commit `A`'s long-form hash.

Comment: This works when the branch is not merged yet. But for branch, that has been already merged, it shows hash of last commit in branch (`G` hash).

Comment: You're right, this is not for merged branches, I have to search further since what you want is indeed more tricky to get. I've edited in the meantime to avoid misleading people.