# How is git log organizing my commit history after merging 2 branches?

Tags: git, logging, merge, commit

I have two git branches that produce logs like so:

```
Branch A
commit xyz @ 11:00 am
commit yut @ 11:10 am
commit mot @ 11:30 am

Branch B
commit xyz @ 11::00 am
commit shu @ 11: 20 am
commit yam @ 11: 40 am

Merge Branch B to Branch A
```

Now when i check the logs of Branch A, it shows as follows:

```
Branch A
commit xyz @ 11:00 am
commit yut @ 11:10 am
commit shu @ 11: 20 am
commit mot @ 11:30 am
commit yam @ 11: 40 am
commit merge Branch B 11:50 am
```

but when i check the commit object of shu, its parent hash is xyz and not yut (despite yut preceding it in the logs).

is the git log function just reading the commit history of both branches (through the merge commit) and then displaying them in order of 'time' committed?

wouldnt differences in local time on each computer around the world mess this order up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Besides [LeGEC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63323196/1256452), it's worth considering how `git log` *could* show commits.  This is important because `git log` actually *does* implement many of these options.

Remember that each commit is itself numbered with a unique hash ID, *and* each commit stores the numbers—the hash IDs—of its *parent* (predecessor) commit or commits.  Most commits have a single parent, which produces a nice, simple linear (but backwards-looking) chain of commits:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the *last* commit in the chain.  The uppercase `H` here stands in for the actual hash ID of the commit (whatever that may be).  The *contents* of commit `H` come in two parts:

- The main data of the commit hold the snapshot of all the files that make up that commit.
- The *metadata* for that commit contain information such as the name and email address of the author of the commit.  In this metadata, commit `H` stores the actual hash ID of earlier commit `G`.

We say, then, that commit `H` *points to* earlier commit `G`.  Git uses a hash ID to find the actual commit, in its big database of all the Git objects in the repository, so as long as we give Git hash ID `H`, it can use that to read out the contents, including hash ID `G`.  Then it has a hash ID for `G`, which it can use to read out `G`'s contents, which include hash ID `F`, which it can use to read `F`'s contents, and so on.

The place that Git gets `H`'s hash ID is from the *branch name:*

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

for instance.  We say that the branch name *points to* the last commit in the chain.

What's special about a *merge commit* is that instead of a single parent, it has two parents.  That is, the merge commit points (backwards, as always) to *two* commits instead of just one:

```
...--I--J   <-- branch1
         \
          M   <-- merged
         /
...--K--L   <-- branch2
```

Here, we have made a branch name `merged` that points to commit `M`.  From `M`, we can go backwards to *either* `J` *or* `L`, when we work one commit at a time (as Git tends to do).

But what if, as `git log` would like, we want to look at *both* commits `J` *and* `L`?  If we're forced to work with one commit at a time—as we often are—how will we manage that?

The method that Git uses is to put commit hash IDs into a [*queue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)), or more specifically, a ]*priority queue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  That is, if we're on branch `merged` and we run `git log`, Git:

1. Uses the name `merged` to find `M`'s commit hash ID, and puts `M` in the queue.  The queue now has just one entry.
2. Takes the first commit off the queue (making the queue empty) and examines it.  This commit is a *merge commit*, so `git log` doesn't print much about it, at least by default—that is, if you ask for patches with `git log -p` you don't get one—but it *does* put *both parents* into the queue.

   Since the queue has an ordering property—higher priority commits get used before lower priority commits—the priority determines which of `J` or `L` will get shown next.
3. Takes the first commit off the queue (leaving one commit in the queue) and examines it.  This commit, whether it is `J` or `L`, is an *ordinary commit* with a single parent, so Git prints it and includes a patch if you asked for one.<sup>1</sup>  Then Git puts the parent of this commit, whichever parent that is, into the queue (so that there are again two entries in the queue).
4. Repeats the above "take first commit from the queue and work with it" until the queue is eventually empty—this can take a *long* time!—or you tell Git to quit.

The *order in which you see commits* therefore depends on what you've set up about the priorities.

Besides the various ordering options, though, there's a very important option, `--first-parent`, that affects how Git handles merge commits.  In particular, we saw in step 2 above that Git put *both* parents of merge commit `M` into the queue.  If we use `--first-parent`, Git *doesn't* put both parents into the queue.  Instead, Git puts only the *first* parent of `M` into the queue.

The *first parent* of a merge is therefore pretty important.  But which parent is the first one?  The answer to that depends on *how* whoever did the merge, did the merge.

When you run:

```
git checkout somebranch
git merge otherbranch
```

and Git actually makes a merge commit like `M`, the *first* parent of the new merge commit is the commit you checked out in the `git checkout` step: the last commit of `somebranch` before you make the merge.  The *second* parent—the one that `git log --first-parent` will *ignore*—is the other branch's last commit (at the time you run `git merge`, that is).  So if you have:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- somebranch (HEAD)

 ...--J--K--L   <-- otherbranch
```

—the `(HEAD)` here indicates that you did a `git checkout somebranch` and got commit `I`—and run `git merge otherbranch`, the new merge commit will have commit `I` as its *first* parent, and `L` as its second:

```
...--G--H--I--M   <-- somebranch (HEAD)
             /
 ...--J--K--L   <-- otherbranch
```

Note that `M` is now the *last* commit on `somebranch`, and commits `J-K-L` are now on *both branches*.  The `git log` command will therefore show commits `J-K-L` *unless you use `--first-parent`*, which specifically *excludes* these commits because they came from a side branch.

Note that using `git pull` can result in what some call [foxtrot merges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452), where `git log --first-parent` shows you the commits you *didn't* want to see, instead of the ones that you did.  That's because `git merge` treats *your* (local) branch as the main line, instead of treating the other Git's branch as the main line and your work as a feature-branch.  On the other hand, this can be the order you *do* prefer.  As the person in control—the one making the merge—it is up to you to decide whether to have a preference, and if so, what that preference is.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to view which commit is the parent of which, things should be clearer if you add the --graph option :

```
git log --graph
```

Regarding the display order of commits, see the [Commit ordering](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering) section in `git help log` :

default ordering is :

> --date-order
>
> Show no parents before all of its children are shown, but otherwise show commits in the commit timestamp order.