# Is there a way to get Git to print out the "fast forward" tasks between two commits?

Tags: git, fast-forward

When you run `git pull` from a remote repo, you'll see a list of all the files updated and the number of lines changed, along with approximate ratios of insertions/deletions. You'll also see any created, renamed, deleted and mode-changed files. For example:

```
Updating 5524541..cff1e7a
Fast-forward
 .gitignore                                 |   4 +-
 .vscode/settings.json                      |   7 ++
 README.md                                  |  40 ++++++-
 clean.sh => dev_scripts/clean.sh           |   0
 dev_scripts/main.sh                        |   2 +-
 ... many more files here ...
 41 files changed, 1044 insertions(+), 502 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .vscode/settings.json
 rename clean.sh => dev_scripts/clean.sh (100%)
 delete mode 100644 dev_scripts/test_old.py
 create mode 100644 postinstall/2.0.7_00_fix_missing_models.py
 create mode 100644 test/csv_test.py
```

Is there a way to get output similar to this but by specifying the starting and ending commit on a local repo? I basically want the same output as the `git pull` fast forward output, but without actually performing any actions, just displaying what *would* happen if I were in a scenario where my local repo was at commit A and the remote was at commit B and I did a pull (even though both commits are already in my local repo). Or, more succinctly perhaps, I want to see a summary list of what would happen if I were to start at commit A and checkout commit B.

I know about `git diff` which basically performs the desired function (showing me what the changes are between two commits), but it prints out the entire diff between the two commits (I believe it comes out in something suitable for `patch`?), whereas I'm just looking for the summary report like the fast-forward report.

Comment: git diff --stats ?

Comment: I think, git diff --stat --summary is close to what you are looking for. One provides the changes within files (stat), the other mode changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [KateYoak suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271206/is-there-a-way-to-get-git-to-print-out-the-fast-forward-tasks-between-two-comm#comment118907547_67271206), you need `git diff --stat --summary` here.  The tricky part is finding the correct commits (or hash IDs) to feed as the two inputs to this `git diff`.  They are, however, right there on your screen:

> ```
> Updating 5524541..cff1e7a
> ```

You can also find them in `HEAD@{1}` and `HEAD` (or `HEAD@{0}`) for some time, although eventually these numbers increment so that they are in `HEAD@{2}` and `HEAD@{1}`, then in `HEAD@{3}` and `HEAD@{2}`, and so on.  You can use the reflog for the branch you are on, as these numbers increment a bit more slowly in general.  If you were on branch `dev` for instance these would be `dev@{1}` and `dev@{0}`, etc.

(Note that these two commit hash IDs are unlikely ever to re-occur for anyone else, so there's no point saving them from this answer.  Because they're *shortened* hash IDs, they're more likely than the 1-in-2<sup>160</sup> chance for any one full hash ID, but they're still remarkably unlikely.)

#### Why this works

> When you run `git pull` ...

... you are actually running `git fetch` and then a second Git command.  In your case, the second Git command was `git merge`.

The `git fetch` operation obtained some new commit(s) from some other Git repository.  In this case:

> ```
> Updating 5524541..cff1e7a
> ```

it obtained some series of commits ending in commit `cff1e7a`.

At this time, your *current* commit, as found by `HEAD` connecting to some branch name, was `5524541`.  That is, if you were on branch `dev`, the *name* `dev` *meant* `5524541`.

New-to-you commit `cff1e7a` was "strictly ahead of" commit `5524541`, so when your `git pull` ran `git merge`—which allowed a *fast-forward operation* instead of a merge—your `git merge` **did** a fast-forward operation, changing your current branch name so that it referred to `cff1e7a`.<sup>1</sup>  This is all quite normal, but it's moving very fast and you probably didn't see it happen.

Finally, whatever the `git merge` did, Git produces a `git diff --stat --summary` from the old commit—i.e., `5524541`—to the new commit, `cff1e7a`.  That's the output you saw.  So, if you want to reproduce that output, run `git diff --stat --summary 5524541 cff1e7a`.

Note that there's no need to use the two-dot syntax:

```
git diff --stat --summary 5524541 cff1e7a
```

and:

```
git diff --stat --summary 5524541..cff1e7a
```

do *exactly the same thing*.  It's easier to type one space than two dots, and the one-space version is more logical than the two-dot version, considering the way `git diff` works, so it's the one I recommend.

You can, if you like, use only one of `--stat` or `--summary`.  The `--stat` part is everything up to and including:

> ```
>  41 files changed, 1044 insertions(+), 502 deletions(-)
> ```

and the `--summary` part is the rest.

---

<sup>1</sup>Not all merges can be fast-forwards, but all fast-forwards can be done as true merges, if you prefer that.  A fast-forward occurs when the new value to be stored in some reference is a descendant of the hash ID stored in that reference now.  A branch name is a particular form of reference, so branch names *can* be fast-forward-ed.  Allowing `git merge` to do fast-forwards is the default.  So when `git pull` runs `git merge`, fast-forward operations are common.

Although this is a matter of opinion, some of us (myself included) think that *only* fast-forward operations are really appropriate when using `git pull`.  So this is a good thing.  When `git pull` results in a true merge, it produces what some call a *foxtrot merge*, which is typically in some sense "backwards".  See also [GIT: How can I prevent foxtrot merges in my 'master' branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452)  To some extent this is minor, but foxtrot merges are still not *good*.

Comment: +100 Exactly what I needed and an excellent explanation of everything! :)