# git log distinguish merged commits from other branch

Tags: git

NOTE: The solution presented below (which does not work as expected) was found by searching SO :-)

I want to list all commits of **current** branch, ignoring merges from other branch, like this:

```
$ git status
On branch 2021050704
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/2021050704'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
*   51fa955 2021-05-07 | schema update (HEAD -> 2021050704, origin/2021050704) [xrfang]
|\  
| * 5b542c5 2021-05-07 | schema update (origin/2021050703, 2021050703) [xrfang]
|/  
* b69d581 2021-05-07 | removed redundant row_format specifier [xrfang]
* 39685bb 2021-05-06 | added collect_invasion series [xrfang]
```

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short --no-merges
* 5b542c5 2021-05-07 | schema update (origin/2021050703, 2021050703) [xrfang]
* b69d581 2021-05-07 | removed redundant row_format specifier [xrfang]
* 39685bb 2021-05-06 | added collect_invasion series [xrfang]
```

Now the problem is, with **--no-merge**, it get rid of `51fa955`, but what I want is to eliminate `5b542c5`, which is from branch `2021050703`, and my current branch is `2021050704`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out after a minute that `--first-parent` is exactly what I need:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short --first-parent
* 51fa955 2021-05-07 | schema update (HEAD -> 2021050704, origin/2021050704) [xrfang]
* b69d581 2021-05-07 | removed redundant row_format specifier [xrfang]
* 39685bb 2021-05-06 | added collect_invasion series [xrfang]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that commit `5b542c5` *is* on your branch.  In Git, commits are often on multiple branches, and a merge commit typically causes one or more commits that were not on the branch before, to be on the branch now.

That aside, the `--first-parent` option is probably what you want.  It tells Git that, upon encountering a merge, Git should follow *only* the *first* parent commit of that merge commit, ignoring second and any additional parents.  Since the *first* parent of a new merge commit made by `git merge` is the commit that *was* the tip of the branch before running `git merge`, this will get the stream of commits you want—provided the commits were made by running `git merge` on the intended branch.

This will malfunction (sort of—by definition it's *correct*, but usually these aren't the commits you *wanted*) if someone used `git pull` to make what some people refer to as a [foxtrot merge](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452).