# Git merge: possible to duplicate directory? trying to manage multiple versions in one repo

Tags: git, git-merge

I'll start by saying that I'm pretty new to git, and have mainly been using it with Atom's built-in plug-in (as well as Git-plus).

When I deploy to production, I'm going to need multiple versions of my code each in its own directory.
My initial thought was to only manage one version of the code (in **Dev** branch) in a directory called `dev`, and when a version is ready: tag it, then merge into **Release** branch. In here I would run a script to change the namespaces, directory name (`dev` --> `v1`), etc. Then merge this into **Main**.

```
DEV                    RELEASE (pre-script)   RELEASE (post-script)  MAIN (PRODUCTION)
======================================================================================
app/                   app/                   app/                   app/
|--src/                |--src/                |--src/                |--src/                
|----globals/          |----globals/          |----globals/          |----globals/
|----api/              |----api/              |----api/              |----api/
|------dev/            |------dev/            |------v1/             |------v1/
|--------file1-dev     |--------file1-dev     |--------file1-v1      |--------file1-v1
|--------file2-dev     |--------file2-dev     |--------file2-v1      |--------file2-v1
```

Then I go back to **Dev** and begin work on v2 (say I modify `file1` and `file2`, and add a new `file3`) finish it, tag it, merge into **Release**.

#### Here's the issue with this Dev-Release merge!

Git is too smart and adds my v2 changes to **Release**'s `v1` folder instead of adding **Dev**'s `dev` folder like I was mistakingly expecting (on which I would normally run the script to turn it into `v2`). So this is what it looks like:

```
DEV                    RELEASE (pre-script)   RELEASE (what I need)
===================================================================
app/                   app/                   app/
|--src/                |--src/                |--src/                
|----globals/          |----globals/          |----globals/
|----api/              |----api/              |----api/
|------dev/            |------v1/             |------v1/
|--------file1-dev     |--------file1-v1(mod) |--------file1-v1
|--------file2-dev     |--------file2-v1(mod) |--------file2-v1             
|--------file3-dev     |--------file3-dev     |------dev/
                                              |--------file1-dev      
                                              |--------file2-dev      
                                              |--------file3-dev
```

I was expecting the **Release** branch to keep the `v1` folder untouched and bring in the "new" `dev` folder, but it wasn't the case. Git recognized that `dev` and `v1` were one and the same so it modifies the file in `v1` instead of creating a new one in `dev`.

The only alternative that I can think of is to manually manage the "production-ready" directory, and do so outside of the repo. In this case I would no longer need the **Release** and **Main** branches, so once I'm done in **Dev** and tagged the version, I would just duplicate my repo into a temp directory (in which I run the script to turn `dev` -> `v1`), then move this `v1` into the separate production directory. This seems a little silly and error-prone, but doable.

Any thoughts, comments, solutions, or even feedback? *I basically thought it was possible to have a dedicated branch that contained all the versions of the code.*

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

You can probably make use of `-X find-renames=` with a high threshold value (e.g., 100), or `-X no-renames` to disable rename detection entirely.

## Long

Personally, I think your best bet is probably a deployment process that happens outside Git, or at least, that does its work outside Git and then just makes a commit from the result.  However, it's easy to get what you want from Git directly (though this has other consequences).  The trick here is that for Git, each commit is literally a snapshot of all files, but, well:

For `git merge` as a command you run—"merge as a verb" as it were—Git locates *three* snapshots, runs *two `git diff`* operations, and then combines the two diffs, including detecting renames.  The combined diffs are then applied to one of the three snapshots.  The goal here is to *combine work*.  This brings up what should be an obvious question, except that a lot of people seem to miss it:

#### If a commit is just a snapshot of files, what does "work" even mean?

The trick here is that a commit isn't **just** a snapshot of files.  A commit is, instead, a snapshot *plus metadata*.  The metadata in a commit include things like the name and email address of the author and committer of the commit in question, and any log message they cared to provide to help future readers of the code figure out *why* they made that particular commit.  But, crucially for Git's internal operation, each commit also includes a list of raw commit hash IDs.

(Let's pause for a moment here to note that every commit has a *unique* hash ID.  When I say unique, I mean *unique:* no other commit anywhere, in any Git repository, is allowed to use that same hash ID.  Every commit you make gets a *new* hash ID, never used before, never to be used again.  In theory, [this can't work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), but in practice it does; the hash ID space is big enough to make collisions unlikely, though it's possible to make them *on purpose:* see [How does the newly found SHA-1 collision affect Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42433126/1256452)  There's a lot more one can explore here, but for practical purposes, each hash ID is unique, which means that the hash ID alone is sufficient to know exactly which commit is which.)

So, given some arbitrary commit whose hash we'll just call `H` for hash, we can have Git look up the commit from the hash ID.  This includes a list of *previous* or *parent* commit hash IDs.  Most commits have exactly one parent here; if `H` is such a commit, it contains some hash ID that, for convenience, let's just call `G`.  We then say that commit `H` *points to* its parent commit `G`, and we can draw that:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Of course `G` is also a commit and therefore points to *its* parent `F`, which in turn is a commit that points to *its* parent:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Induction says that the result of this is a backwards-looking chain of commits: we start at the end, with the *latest* commit, and we can find every earlier commit, all the way back to the very first commit, whose list of previous-commit hash IDs is empty so that we can stop going backwards.

This gives us a simple definition for "the work done in a commit" like commit `H`: we look up the *snapshot* for `H`, but also, using the metadata *in* `H`, we look up the snapshot for its parent `G`.  Then we use `git diff`—a comparison or file differencing engine—to compare the two snapshots.  Whatever spills out of this diff is the *change* made by commit `H`.

#### Branching

Where this becomes particularly interesting is when we get branch-and-merge sequences.  Let's start with the branching part:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

Here, we have a simple tree-like data structure formed by commits where the work diverged after commit `H`.  We made two commits `I-J` on branch `br1` (so that the name `br1` points to the last such commit), and we made two commits `K-L` on branch `br2` (so that the name `br2` points to the last such commit.)

(Here we can pause for another moment to note that internally, in Git, a branch name just *points to* one single commit.  We say that this commit *is* the *last* commit on that branch: it's the *tip commit* of the branch.  *Checking out* the commit involves extracting the saved snapshot in that tip commit, and then that branch name is the *current branch* and that commit is the *current commit*.  Then, if we make a *new* commit without changing branches, the new commit gets a new unique hash ID and points to the current commit as its parent, and then Git simply *stuffs the new hash ID into the branch name* so that the name now points to the new commit.  That's how we got our divergent situation: we had two names both pointing to `H`.  We advanced one, making `I` and `J`, then went back to the *other name* to get `H` again and then advanced the *other* name to make `K-L`.)

#### Merging

Now that we have this branch-y structure in the repository, we can see how `git merge` will do its "combine changes" work.  We *check out* one of `br1` or `br2` (or use `git switch` to make it current and check out its tip commit, which means the same thing but was a new command in Git 2.23 because `git checkout` is overly complicated and does too many things).  Let's say we switch to `br1` here, and annotate it by attaching the special name `HEAD` to the branch name (which is in fact what Git does):

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

We then run `git merge br2`.  Git locates three commits:

- commit `J` (`--ours`) because it is our current commit;
- commit `L` (`--theirs`) because it is the commit we named on the command line, using the branch name, which translates to the tip commit of that branch; and
- commit `H` because it is the *best commit that's on **both** branches* (or technically, the [lowest common ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs)<sup>1</sup>).

So Git now runs `git diff` using the snapshot in `H` as the *merge base* commit, against the snapshot in `J`, to see "what we changed".  Then Git runs `git diff` using the same merge-base snapshot against the snapshot in `K` to see "what they changed".  The resulting line-by-line diffs can now be combined by a simple and stupid text-combination algorithm.  Where the diffs don't overlap or abut, Git just takes both sets of changes.  Where the diffs *do* overlap, Git takes one copy of the change if and only if they overlap *exactly*.  Where the diffs overlap and don't match, or simply abut,<sup>2</sup> Git will declare a *merge conflict*, stop the merge in the middle, and make you fix up the mess.  We'll skip over all these details for space reasons here, though.

Then, having combined the two sets of diffs, Git applies the *combined* diffs to the snapshot in the *merge base* commit—i.e., commit `H`.  This "keeps our changes and adds theirs", or equivalently, "keeps their changes and adds ours": the result is symmetric.<sup>3</sup>  However, the *merge commit* is not quite symmetric.  Git now makes a new commit of type "merge commit", which we can draw this way:

```
          I--J
         /    \₁
...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         \    /²
          K--L   <-- br2
```

New commit `M` goes on the current branch, like any new commit, so the name `br1` now points to `M`.  New commit `M` has a snapshot, like any commit: that's the snapshot that the merge-as-a-verb, combine-work process generated.  But this merge commit differs from other commits in exactly one way: it has a list of *two* parents, rather than just one.  It points backwards to commit `J`, the previous branch-tip commit, as its *first parent* (hence the tiny `1`), and points backwards to commit `L` as its *second parent* (hence the tiny `2`).<sup>4</sup>

Most of the time, we don't care about first-vs-non-first merge parents, but we can run `git log --first-parent` to follow only the *first* parent at merge commits, which lets us view a "main line of development" without having to see every commit on every feature: we see only the merge commits that bring in the feature.  If you like this idea of being able to use `--first-parent`, you may wish to avoid `git pull`, at least if used without `--rebase`: see [How can I prevent foxtrot merges in my 'master' branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452)  But that's another matter; let's press on.

---

<sup>1</sup>As we're using the full Directed Acyclic Graph version of LCA here, there can be more than one LCA.  See one of my longer answers about recursive merge to see how Git handles this.

<sup>2</sup>Some merge algorithms allow abutting changes without complaint; Git doesn't, and there's no selector knob to turn to enable them.  That's just a choice Git made at some point: it's not really fundamental to anything.

<sup>3</sup>In the case of *conflicts*, you can use flags that make the result asymmetric; we're only really concerned with the simple conflict-free case here.

<sup>4</sup>Git supports something it calls an *octopus merge*, in which a merge commit has three or more parents.  We won't cover these here either but they don't really do anything special, they just make the Directed Acyclic Graph harder to think about.

---

#### Merges provide new merge bases

If we look at the way main-lines and feature branches work in a simplified world, we can see how each feature can be provided as a sort of "merge bubble" that joins into the main line:

```
                    o--o--o   <-- feature2
                   /       \
...--o--B---------M---------N   <-- main
         \       /
          o--o--o   <-- feature1
```

The merge base at `M`, back when we make `M`, is commit `B`; the merge base at `N`, once we make `N`, is commit `M`.  These are much simpler than real-world merges though, which may get messy like this:

```
...--o--B----o----M--P--o--S--o   <-- main
         \       /    \     \
          o--o--L--N---R--o--T   <-- feature
```

Here we made a branch for a feature, branching off from commit `B`, which was the merge base when we made an early merge `M` back into the mainline:

```
...--o--B----o----M   <-- main
         \       /
          o--o--L   <-- feature
```

But we were not yet done with the feature, so we went on to make a new commit `N` on feature, then had an important fix to go directly to `main` which became commit `P` (I skipped the letter `O` because it's too similar to the lowercase `o` for the more boring commits here):

```
...--o--B----o----M--P   <-- main
         \       /
          o--o--L--N   <-- feature
```

We decided to merge the fix `P` into `feature` too, resulting in merge commit `R` (skipping `Q` as it also is too similar to `O` or `o`):

```
...--o--B----o----M--P   <-- main
         \       /    \
          o--o--L--N---R   <-- feature
```

But when we made `R`, what was the merge base?  The merge base is the best *shared* commit, i.e., the best commit that's on *both branches*.  That's no longer commit `B`, because if we start with `N` and work backwards, we see commit `N` and then `L`, and if we start with `P` and work backwards, we encounter commits `M` and then both `o` and `L` at the same time.  So the *merge base* is now commit `L`!

Later, after making a few more commits, we have:

```
...--o--B----o----M--P--o--S   <-- main
         \       /    \
          o--o--L--N---R--o   <-- feature
```

Working our way back from the tip commit of `feature`, we pass through `R` and arrive at `P`; we arrive at `P` working backwards from `S` too, so `P` is our merge base here, when we make new commit `T`, and then add another commit to `main`:

```
...--o--B----o----M--P--o--S--o   <-- main
         \       /    \     \
          o--o--L--N---R--o--T   <-- feature
```

At this point commit `S` is now the merge base between `main` and `feature`.  So you can see how the *merge base*, which is kind of the main control point for `git merge`, *moves* over time *because* we made earlier merge commits.

In essence, we have two rules:

- the commits in the repository *are* the history in the repository;
- *merge* commits in the repository provide for *future* merge bases.

That means that when we *do* make a *merge commit*, its snapshot and parentage are crucial to a *future* merge.  It will help determine a future merge base, and the merge commit itself, or some derivative of it, will provide one of the snapshots that goes into the combining process.

#### Rename detection

When `git merge` runs the two `git diff` commands that it runs, it's `git diff` that decides whether some file was *renamed*.  Renames in Git are *detected* rather than *recorded:* each commit holds a full snapshot of all files, but there is nothing in the data or metadata that says that in commit `I`, file `foo.py` is "the same file" as file `bar.py` in commit `H`, or not.

Other version control systems provide some sort of file identifier, e.g., an "inode number" or "file key" or something, so that we know that `bar.py` got renamed to `foo.py`.  Git does not do this.  Instead, if, looking at commit `H` as a whole, there's a file named `bar.py`, and looking at commit `L` as a whole, there's *no* file named `bar.py` but there's a "new" file named `foo.py`, Git effectively says to itself: *Hey, maybe these are really the same file, just renamed!*

This actually works surprisingly well in a lot of cases.  Git notices: "hey, files X and Y existed on the left and are gone on the right, but new files F1, F2, F3, F4 appeared, maybe X is one of those and Y is one of those".  Git computes a *similarity index* for all such file-pairings (with some tweaking and clever optimizations as this is otherwise *at least* O(mn) with large constants as well, but even then this computation is pretty expensive).  If the similarity index exceeds some minimum threshold, Git will pair up the pairs with the *best*—highest—index values and call those "the same file, but renamed".

You can always run `git diff` manually before a merge:  Use `git merge-base` to find the merge base commit yourself, and then run your own `git diff` commands with `-M` and whatever rename threshold you like.  You may wish to add `--name-status` as well to suppress the actual diff and just get a list of files, including renamed files.  (You might sometimes want `--diff-filter` as well; see [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).)  When the list of renamed files matches what you want, you have found a suitable threshold value.

If you just want to disable rename detection entirely, `git diff` offers `--no-renames` as well.  (Also, `--find-renames=` is a synonym for `-M` here.)

Given the appropriate `-X` options—I like to call these *eXtended strategy options* to help remember the flag letter<sup>5</sup>—`git merge` will pass either `--no-renames` or `--find-renames=number` on to both `git diff` commands.  This will determine which if any renames the `git merge` command "sees".  When `git merge` is combining work, if it sees a rename on one side, and nothing on the other, it takes the rename; if it sees two identical renames, it also takes the rename; and if it sees two different renames, it declares a merge conflict.  These *high level* or *tree level* conflicts at `git merge` time are not subject to resolution through `-X` extended-strategy-options.

Simply disabling rename detection entirely may work well for your particular use case.  Note though that Git *does not record the merge options used here*, and if you ever run `git rebase -r` aka `git rebase --rebase-merges`, Git will *re-perform* any merges, but because it didn't *save* the options you used, will perform those merges as *default* merges, with the default rename detection.

---

<sup>5</sup>Git documentation calls the `-s` option the *strategy* option, and the `-X` options the *strategy option* options.  So we have `-s`, strategy, and `-X`, strategy-option, which is just confusing.  But if we think of these as `-s` = strategy, `-X` = eXtended-(strategy-)-option, then it all makes sense.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation! It seems that `--no-renames` does exactly what I need (I tried both that and the `-M` options with `git diff`, but the similarity index varies too much as a lot of those files are very small). Question is, how exactly do I tell the `git merge` to internally use `git diff`s with the `--no-renames` flag? (not sure I understand the "strategies" you mentioned)

Comment: Ok, so after a bit of testing I realized that `git merge -s recursive -Xno-renames release dev` still doesn't do what I need because it only adds new/modified files into the "new" `dev` folder. What I would want it to do is bring over the entire **Dev** branch's `dev` directory, because it does not appear in the **Release** branch

Comment: Ok so it seems like the closest thing I can do is to `git checkout dev -- path/to/dev/folder` to import the entire `dev` directory from the **Dev** branch (which is where 99% of the versioned code lives); then perform a regular `git merge --no-ff` to merge any remaining files that live outside the `dev` directory; then run my script

Comment: Yes, this sort of thing is why my opinion was (and still is) that you're probably best served with a non-Git tool to prepare the release: a deployment tool, not a source-code versioning tool.